# Iterating over multidimensional PHP Object and changin values by reference

Tags: php, object, reference, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a php object and changing each string value by reference, but something is just not working. In some arrays the strings will not be changed. Anyone has an idea why? Or has a suggestion on how to solve the task?

Here is my code:

```
recursive_object_string_changer($object);

function recursive_object_string_changer($object)
{
    if($object == null) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($object as &$attribute) {
        if (is_string($attribute)) {
            $attribute = $attribute."!";
        } else if (is_array($attribute)) {
            recursive_object_string_changer($attribute);
        } else if (is_object($attribute)) {
            recursive_object_string_changer($attribute);
        }
    }
    unset($attribute);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you make a very simple example object with `stdClass` for us to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to make the function's signature also accept the initial object as a reference so that the recursion works on subsequent calls.

```php
recursive_object_string_changer($object);

function recursive_object_string_changer(&$object)
{
    if ($object === null) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($object as &$attribute) {
        if (is_string($attribute)) {
            $attribute .= "!";
        } elseif (is_array($attribute)) {
            recursive_object_string_changer($attribute);
        } elseif (is_object($attribute)) {
            recursive_object_string_changer($attribute);
        }
    }
    unset($attribute);
}
```

I used this for a sample:

```php
$object = new stdClass();
$object->string = 'Test';
$object->array = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
];

$subObject = new stdClass();
$subObject->string = 'Another String';
$object->object = $subObject;
```

Which produces:

```php
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["string"]=>
  string(5) "Test!"
  ["array"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a!"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "b!"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "c!"
  }
  ["object"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["string"]=>
    string(15) "Another String!"
  }
}
```

You might always want to add a guard before the `for` loop to make sure that `$object` is an array or an object in the first place.